# Modal do not want to open - Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I want to make my modal apper, but I can not to do it.
This is my code:

```
<div class="container h-100">
            <div class="row justify-content-sm-center h-100">
                <div class="col-xxl-4 col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-7 col-sm-9">
                    <div class="text-center my-5">
                        <img src="img/logo-branca.png" alt="logo" width="100">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card shadow-lg">
                        <div class="card-body p-5">
                            <h1 class="fs-4 card-title fw-bold mb-4">CEP</h1>
                            <form method="POST" action = "autenticar.php">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <input id="cep" type="number" class="form-control" name="cep" value="" required="required">
                                    
                                </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ms-auto">
                                        Pesquisar
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer py-3 border-0">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
                                    BUTTON TO OPEN THE MODAL
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center mt-5 text-muted">
                        Copyright &copy; 2021 &mdash; Rodrigo Franco 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

If you need to see my project compleatly, just go to this [link](http://entrefolhas.atwebpages.com) or if you want to make download the project, just go [here](https://mega.nz/file/vAlWkBRD#rawpsfasyfjdf77v5ibBisiNQI_xgeBiDsVoRoo51aA)

Comment: did you add the Bootstrap js files to your project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not loading Bootstrap's javascript files, simply add:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

To the head of your document and the modal works.

Resources: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/

Comment: thanks bro. Now its working!